# Define custom function and loop over range in Google Apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a custom function in Google Apps Script that takes on a range (in my case a single row e.g. Sheet1!A2:E2 containing strings), lower-case all strings and modifies them.

1 row of output should contain strings in lower case
2 row of output should contain strings with a suffix e.g. ".info" added
3 row of output should contain stings with a prefix and suffix e.g. "http://" + string + ".info"
…

My approach was the below, however doesn't work:

```js
/**
* @customfunction
*/
function myFunction (range) {

  var result = [];
  
  for (var i = 0; i < range[0].length; i++) {
    if ( range[i] == "") {
      break;
    } else {
      for (var j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
        result.push(range[i]);
      }
    }
  }
  return result;
};
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6oie.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite understand English, but you may need to

```
function myFunction(range) {
    if (range.length > 1) return 'One row required';

    var result = [
        [],
        [],
        []
    ];

    for (var i = 0; i < range[0].length; i++) {
        if (range[0][i] && range[0][i].toLowerCase) {
            var str = range[0][i].toLowerCase();
            result[0][i] = str;
            result[1][i] = str + '.info';
            result[2][i] = 'https://' + str + '.info';
        }
    }
    return result;
};
```

[image]